# Multi module pydoc html documentation

Tags: python, html, pydoc

I create a single module html documentation using pydoc like:
`pdoc --html file.py`

Is it possible to generate pydoc documentation for many modules in one html file?

Comment: you mean pdoc or pydoc? Those are both real documentation tools. I'm working from memory, but I'm 99% sure pydoc can't do a single page, multimodule HTML report, it is very limited. I'd have to go look it up, but pydoc's competitors are more likely to support it.